# Reshaping Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
X1     variables   data
2.6    X2          2.5
       X3          2.9
```

How can I reshape it to something like this:

```
variables    data
X1           2.6
X2           2.5
X3           2.9
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hello! Please share your work so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
  melt(setDT(df1), id.var='variables', na.rm=TRUE, value.name='data')[
    variable!='data',  variables:= variable][,variable:=NULL][]
  #    variables data
  #1:        X1  2.6
  #2:        X2  2.5
  #3:        X3  2.9
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(2.6, NA), variables = c("X2", "X3"),
  data = c(2.5, 
  2.9)), .Names = c("X1", "variables", "data"), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_row <- c(names(df1)[1], (df1[, 1][1]))
df1 <- df1[, 2:3 ]
df2 <- rbind(first_row, df1)

df2
#  variables data
#        X1  2.6
#        X2  2.5
#        X3  2.9
```

Comment: Of course it can be literally moved, the goal is to write an expression that could do it without direct reference.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that, although it was implied... :)